# In my bathroom, should I install sheet vinyl on hardiebacker board or plywood?

Tags: flooring, vinyl-flooring, vinyl, underlayment, transition

I don't want to deal with seams or grout, so I'm going with vinyl sheet flooring in my bathroom. The bathroom floor is low at the transition to the hallway, and also at the toilet flange, so I'd like to raise it around a half inch. Should I put down more plywood, or cement board to raise it, and can I install the new vinyl sheet directly to it assuming its a smooth surface?

Comment: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/253007/install-vinyl-plank-flooring-on-top-of-cement-board-backer-board-as-underlaym

Comment: Not sure how that applies, @popham...

Answer (score 0):

Hardiebacker has a smooth side if you decide on that. The adhesive will work fine on Hardiebacker if it lists concrete as an allowable substrate. In a bathroom, both Exposure 1 plywood (people will call it "exterior" plywood) and Hardieboard are acceptable. I would just avoid OSB (or particleboard) in a bathroom. The Hardieboard's score-and-snap might make it easier to work with. Just be sure to use alkali resistant fasteners if you use the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Plywood.

The purpose of cement board is to have something that is "waterproof", something that doesn't shift when humidity/temp changes and something easy to adhere to.

None of these things are needed for vinyl sheet flooring.

Plywood on the other hand will provide more stiffness and will structurally improve the flooring (less bounce and movement).   You don't have to worry about it getting wet because vinyl sheet flooring should be able to create a pool if installed right.   I bring vinyl sheet a good inch on the walls and trim over where I can.

I cannot make any case for using concrete board of any kind.   Even you wanted to tile in the future you would just use a waterproof underlayment (ditra) over the plywood.